# How to set an image instead of white color in this code?

Tags: java

I am trying to make some sort of a Paint program but in JAVA. With the graphics class, I can set a painting space and draw on it. I want this space to be an image instead of a white space and despite all my efforts, I can't. If I succeed, I can't draw over the image.

non-working code with image: https://pastebin.com/zNnWGjgS

```
Stackoverflow forces me to put some code here but it's too long
```

working code without image: https://pastebin.com/r1nFHY9c

```
Stackoverflow forces me to put some code here but it's too long
```

Please help me guys. Thank you.

Comment: Paste the specific code that, in your opinion, deals with the problem. If someone thinks the problem might be somewhere else, they'll ask for that bit of code. Don't expect strangers to read your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

With just a quick look at you paintComponent I can see that you are confused. All you want to do is to load the graphics of your image into the `Graphics2D g2` and draw lines on it. In your non working example you :

1. Create a new image with `createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);`
2. You set the graphics g2 to empty Image graphics
3. You load the `image` and discard the previous initialization leaving the g2 with the empty one.
4. You drawing the image, while all the changes are made to the g2 graphics.

To fix your error just change the paintComponent to :

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (image == null) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.imgur.com/mjxu50B.png"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

        // enable antialiasing
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

PS. In future post try to post the non working example only and try to keep it as simple as you can.